# How to use git plugin in JQAssistant command line?

Tags: plugins, jgit, jqassistant

Paragraph below mentioned we can use git plugin in JQAssistant commmand line:

> If you want to add the git plugins to your jQAssistant downloaded commandline installation you currently have to manually add the an org.eclipse.jgit jar file to the plugins directory of jqassistant: Use at least version 4.8.0.201706111038-r from Maven Central.

https://github.com/kontext-e/jqassistant-plugins

I added JGit jar and tried command below but JQAssistant doesn't collect Git information (commits, branches, authors,..):

```
jqassistant.sh scan -f .git
```

What arguments do we need to pass to scan task to be able collect Git information?

Comment: It should work as you described. When you run this command, do you see a log like this: 2022-06-09 09:09:44.818 [main] INFO PluginConfigurationReaderImpl - [Asciidoc Report, ..., Git, ...]. As you can see here, the Git plugin is mentioned to be used. In the following lines you should have something like:  2022-06-09 09:09:48.593 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Entering <path_to_your_project>/.git followed by 2022-06-09 09:09:48.662 [main] INFO GitScannerPlugin - Accepted Git project in '<path_to_your_project>\.git' and finally ... Leaving /.git (421 entries, 10124 ms)

Comment: Thanks! That was a great hint. I also realized beside Jgit I had to copy git plugin itself to plugin folder. It is working now.